# Get root access inside mssql docker container

Tags: sql-server, linux, docker, containers, root

I created a MSSQL docker container based on the official image provided by Microsoft (https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server).

I started a bash shell inside the running container and tried to delete some files.

```
sudo docker exec -it sql1 "bash"
```

Inside the container it is using the `mssql` account (by default).

And there seems to be some permission issues when I tried to delete the files.

```
rm -f *.csv
rm: cannot remove 'xxx.csv': Operation not permitted
```

How can I obtain the root permission to delete the file? I am not sure what default password I can use to run `rm` as root.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 22):

You can specify the user as an argument:

```bash
sudo docker exec -it --user root sql1 "bash"
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem where the Docker container kept crashing, and the cause seems to be missing permissions for the server to run. If you are using `docker-compose.yml`, try the following. The `user: root` part should do the trick and run the container with root privilege:

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  mssql:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
    container_name: mssql
    user: root
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - SA_PASSWORD=YourPassword
```

PS: There may be a security concern when running the server as root so please chip in if anyone knows how to handle this. However, [using root privilege seems to be accepted by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-docker-container-security?view=sql-server-ver16#run-the-non-root-container-as-the-root-user).

Answer (score 0):

If you are on docker-compose

```
user:
      0:0
```